# How to dynamically create a g element in svg

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object id="oo" data="Dynamic_grouping.svg" style="position:fixed;width: 900px;height:750px;bottom:  -220px;right: 180px;">

    </object>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                    var far=document.getElementById("oo")
                    far.addEventListener("load", function (){
                    var svgDoc=far.contentDocument;
                    var svgRoot=svgDoc.documentElement;
                    document.getElementById("bar").onclick=function(){

                    var g = svgDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
                    g.setAttribute('id', 'group');
                    g.setAttribute('shape-rendering', 'inherit');
                    g.setAttribute('pointer-events', 'all');


                    var use = svgDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use")
                    use.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", "#g1")
                    use.setAttributeNS(null,"id", "u")
                    svgRoot.appendChild(use)

                    var create_bar=svgDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect")
                    create_bar.setAttribute("id", "r_bar")
                    create_bar.setAttribute("fill", "cream")
                    create_bar.setAttribute("x", "300px")
                    create_bar.setAttribute("y", "50px")
                    create_bar.setAttribute("width", "100px")
                    create_bar.setAttribute("height", "30px")
                    create_bar.setAttribute("pointer-events", "inherit")
                    g.appendChild(create_bar)

                    var cir = svgDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
                    cir.setAttribute( "id","cir")
                    cir.setAttribute( "cx","320px")
                    cir.setAttribute( "cy","65px")
                    cir.setAttribute( "r","10px")
                    cir.setAttribute('fill', 'red')
                    cir.setAttribute('pointer-events', 'inherit')
                    g.appendChild(cir)

                    svgRoot.appendChild(g)
                }
                    var btn_id=document.getElementById('bar2')
                    btn_id.onclick=function()
                    {
                        var a=svgDoc.getElementById('r_bar')
                        var b=svgDoc.getElementById('group')
                        var c=svgDoc.getElementById('cir')
                        var d=svgDoc.getElementById('u')

                        alert(a.id+".."+b.id+".."+c.id+".."+d.id)
                    }

          },false)


    </script>
    <input type="button" id="bar" value="Ribbon_Bar">
    <input type="button" id="bar2" value="ID">
</html>
```

Comment: This question must have been updated/changed since it was first posted. It's no longer a question, and it doesn't have the errors that the answer points out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is the cause of the error:

> use.setAttribute('xlink:href','g1')

The proper syntax is:

```
use.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", "#g1")
```

Basically you're missing a hashmark for the link, and you should use the namespace-aware setAttributeNS.

Regarding setAttribute, you should be aware that using prefixes there is not recommended. From [DOM 3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Namespaces-Considerations) (the last paragraph in that section):

> DOM Level 1 methods are namespace
>   ignorant. Therefore, while it is safe
>   to use these methods when not dealing
>   with namespaces, using them and the
>   new ones at the same time should be
>   avoided.

Comment: i have update the code Erik but still not progress...! i have chnge the code and update the new one..please have a look ...Kindly

Comment: Erik,

Here is the gist of the functionality I want to incorporate in the web application.

With the mouse, the user can draw a rectangle around svg objects, thereby selecting all the objects. All these objects will be grouped together then and if the user desires, he can move the group to another position and all the objects inside the group would move in unison (maintaining their distance from/to eachother).

Hope this sketches out the kind of functionality I am trying to implement.

Comment: Where's the surrounding html+scripts? If you're trying to capture mouse events on an `<object>` or `<embed>` tag for example then that's not going to work. Does your onclick handler get called? (verify e.g with an alert).

Comment: <body>
        <object id="oo" data="Dynamic_grouping.svg" style="position:fixed;width: 900px;height:750px;bottom:  -220px;right: 180px;">

    </object>

    </body>

Comment: yes my onlick handler is called.....! it working correctly . i think there is a problem in some Dynamic creation little bit problem....!

Comment: on Dynamic creation my rectangle and circle are also created but are not grouped..!

Comment: I don't see any element with id="g1", so the 'use' element won't show anything. What do you mean the rect and the circle are not grouped?

Comment: this was mistakenly happened, i have replace #g t0 #group..!

Comment: i want to group the rect and cicrle dynamically..! using <g> dynamically...!

Comment: All the elements are created as they should (dynamically). Maybe your shapes are not within the visible area? Or maybe I just don't understand the question, in which case I'd encourage you to try to explain more (not here, but in the question above).

Comment: All,

We are working on an SVG web application. 

Above the code I have written, with an effort towards dynamically 'grouping' various shapes using the 'g' tag from SVG. An example, we have various SVG elements (lines, circles, rectangles etc) and when the user selects them together (say by drawing a rectangle around all the above shapes), they all get grouped together. Only there and then does the grouping happen.

So the question is how to we go about dynamically grouping of SVG elements using JS?

Comment: hi Erik i want ur help, i m trying to contact u from ur Opera Blog, but all in vein...any how, kindly help me out, problem i am facing is like this that i am working on svg, i have implemented drag and drop in svg, now i want to implement the Snap to grid functionality in it, i have tried a lot but unable to implement it, i have uploaded the code as well, u can have a view of it, any help will be awesome...here is the link where i uploaded the code.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507784/snap-to-grid-functionality-using-javascript